# ANTLR match ascii range

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to match characters of ASCII ranges.

Example: Match ASCII code points 40-46, 50-133, 135-176.

```
[\40-\46\50-\133\135-\176]
```

How do I achieve this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[\u0040-\u0046\u0050-\u0133\u0135-\u0176]
```

Of course, the `\u....` are hexadecimals.

Comment: works thank you    [\u0028-\u002E\u0032-\u0085\u0087-\u00B0]